# rsync -av -e "ssh", plus a bunch of "includes" with an ending "exclude='*''", not copying all files

Tags: rsync

An rsync command that looks like of like this, `rsync -av -e "ssh" --include="dir1" --include="dir2" --include="dir3" --include="file1" --include="file2" --include="file3" --exclude="*" user@server:/directory1/site/ /dir1`, is not recursively copying the files. In other words, only the files and non-regular files in the /directory1/site directory are being copied and not the files in it's folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rsync includes/excludes are weird.  I strongly suggest you take some time and carefully read the `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES` section of the [man page](https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).  Pay close attention to all the rules since some things simply won't work in what might seem like the obvious way.

```
a trailing "dir_name/***" will match both the directory (as if 
"dir_name/" had been specified) and everything in the directory 
(as if "dir_name/**" had been specified). This behavior was added
in version 2.6.7.
```

So if you wanted the entire contents of a directory you would use `--include="dir3/***"` instead of `--include="dir3"`.